# How to show a cumulative chart of page views in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4, pageviews

How to show a **single page view cumulative chart in GA4**, as it was shown per default in GA Universal?

- Up chart: GA4 > Engagement > Pages and Screens: Multiple charts looks messy and doesn't show the overall trend
- Down chart: GA Universal > Behavior > All pages: the single cumulative chart shows me the overall trend

[image: GA4 page views vers GUniversal page view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a simpler way (than two other answers) I found randomly:

Reports:

[image]

Engagement > Events > click page_view:

[image]

et voilà

[image]

However now I miss the beloved table/list of pages I had in GAUniversal > Behavior > All Pages, the info is now split in 2 screens. (GA4 UI is a total waste IMHO).

[image]

Comment: yep, you pull that info separately now. Again, in explorer. Your tendency to use Reports will cost you at some point. GA4 reports have completely different nature from UA's.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: don't use Reports. There's no report that you couldn't rebuild in Explorer. Plus, the data presented in reports is extremely sampled and imprecise. The biggest issue in Reports is that you can't drill in them. It's far from how it was in UA where you could apply complex filters and drop secondary dimensions. That's no longer possible because Reports in GA4 aren't based on the raw data. They're just screenshots, basically.

The only drawback of the Explore view is that it's a subject to the data retention setting (exactly because it's based on real data), so you may want to [change it](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en) from the default 2 months to 14 months.

In the explorer, you only need pageviews metric. Don't add dimensions at all. Here's how it looks for a property that I switched from UA a few days ago:

[image]

Once I add a page dimension, it starts breaking the graph by pages, which is what one would expect. Otherwise, it's a sum. You still have filters there which don't require you to add dimensions to the graph even if you want to filter by them.

Step by step guide:

1. Go to Explore option here:

[image]

2. Click the new exploration option.
3. Click add metric:

[image]

4. Go to the Page section in Metrics and import Views.
5. Now change your data visualisation to a line graph:

[image]

6. Finally drag and drop your views metric to the Rows section.

They attempted to copy Adobe Analytics, but didn't really have even a tenth of capacity to do that, so that's what we got.

Comment: Thanks @BNazaruk, what a shame Google deprecates GAUniversal and don't provide any descent replacement. I have zero knowledge on GA4 concepts, could you please modify your answer into an actionable step by step tutorial to obtain a chart of all page views summed with below a sortable table of each page view (similar to what we had in GAUniversal)  thanks

Comment: Added the steps.

Comment: Thanks @BNazaruk but no matter the metric I try to import I got the message "No data for this combination of segments, values, filters, and date range. Try editing the variables or settings or remove them." but somehow the GA4 account collects metric since we get the reports chart (see screenshot in the question)?

Comment: make sure your time range is something like a past week. Also make sure the only thing you're importing is the page view.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I randomly found an easier way see my other answer

Answer (score 0):

The procedures below may be used to get a chart of all page visits in GA4 that is summed with a sortable table of each page view below:

1. Select Engagement > Pages and Screens under GA4.
2. Select "Pageviews" under "Add metric" from the drop-down menu.
3. Select "Page path" under "Add dimension" from the drop-down menu.
4. Select "Page title" when you click the "Add dimension" button once more.
5. Select "Page URL" when you click "Add dimension" once more.
6. Select "Page referrer" by clicking "Add dimension" once again.
7. Select "User type" after clicking the "Add dimension" button once again.
8. Select "User country" by clicking "Add dimension" once more.
9. Select "Apply" from the menu.

This will demonstrate.

This will provide a chart with the total number of page views together with a sortable table of each page view in Google Analytics 4.

I hope this is useful.

**Source:**

[[GA4] Analytics dimensions and metrics - Analytics Help - Google Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9143382?hl=en).

[[UA→GA4] Comparing metrics: Google Analytics 4 vs. Universal Analytics.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11986666?hl=en)

[[GA4] Pages and screens report - Computer - Analytics Help.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12926732)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I randomly found an easier way see my other answer